# How to add data (an Array) to jwt token which is generated by Identityserver 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

can anyone can help me on how to add an **array** to **jwt token** of **identityserver4** in the format below .

If array contains no data : { "custom_data" : [] }
  If array contains one element : { "custom_data" : ["one_element"]}
  If array contains multiple elements : { "custom_data" : ["first element","second element"]}

I have tried using **IProfileService** and added data by using **Claims**
sample code :

```
foreach (string element in my_array) {
  userClaims.Add(new Claim("custom_data" , element));
}
```

But in that case what I'm getting is as follows :

if array contains no data : { } here I'm not getting any data
 if array contains one element : { "custom_data" : "one_element"} Here I'm getting it as a string
 if array contains multiple elements : { "custom_data" : ["first element","second element"]} Here I'm getting in a correct way

Comment: What the problem with this approach? IdSrv skips empty keys to keep the token small (there is a limited size of header you can  send per request)? Its no problem either since the Claims Principal extension methods will check for the existance of non existance of it via the `User.HasClaim("custom_data")` method. Empty claims are discarded, single ones passed as string and array as well array, since this uses the least possible characters

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tseng . But is there any other way of adding data to token other than using Claims?

Comment: Did you tried UserInfo endpoint? it behaves exactly in the way you want.

Comment: JWT tokens consist of "just claims" and should only contain information about the identity of the person (sub, name, email, gender etc) on the identity token and scopes on the access token. JWTs are not there to transport permissions or similar

Comment: Highly depends what this data is. If its data that often changes, just let your application manage this, i.e. if it's supposed to be permissions, you would store that in your application (not the identity server application) and use the `sub` (unique user id) to query for this data inside your application

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Noobie3001 I solved this by sending the array elements as space separated string ( userClaims.Add(new Claim("custom_data" , "space separated string")); ). so that from client side they just split the string using single space so they can get the result as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/) post ab follow the advice from the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-05) document:

> To avoid the risks inherent in handling OAuth access tokens from a
> purely browser-based application, implementations may wish to move the
> authorization code exchange and handling of access and refresh tokens
> into a backend component.
>
> The backend component essentially becomes a new authorization server
> for the code running in the browser, issuing its own tokens (e.g. a
> session cookie).  Security of the connection between code running in
> the browser and this backend component is assumed to utilize
> browser-level protection mechanisms.
>
> In this scenario, the backend component may be a confidential client
> which is issued its own client secret.